# Show SnackBar when data Successfully written to Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using this function - which adds a document to my Firestore :

```
Future<void> addUser() {
  // Call the user's CollectionReference to add a new user
  return users
      .add({
        'full_name': fullName, // John Doe
        'company': company, // Stokes and Sons
        'age': age // 42
      })
      .then((value) => print("User Added"))
      .catchError((error) => print("Failed to add user: $error"));
}
```

I would like to display a `successful SnackBar()` when **data has been successfully added to Firestore**

& an `error SnackBar()` when **data failed to being added to Firestore**

How do i do so ?

---

*Here is my SnackBar :*

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(successSnackBar);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this

```
try {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collectionPath').add({
        'full_name': 'John Doe',
        'company': 'Stokes and Sons',
        'age': '42',
      });
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(successSnackBar);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(errorSnackBar);
    }
```

or you can use below expression

```
try {
  
} on FirebaseException catch (e) {

}
```

Moreover, Your function return type is Future void and you are returning Firebase instant. That is not accurate. Remove the `return` keyword in for `Future<void>` type function and make it `asynchronies` as shown below,

```
Future<void> addUser() async {
   await .....
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - but I tried this in Airplane mode & it did not display any snackBar 

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is good I just suggest removing previous snackbars before showing a new one.

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar(); 
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).removeCurrentSnackBar();
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).clearSnackBars();
```

You can choose one from above methods and do like this :

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
            ..hideCurrentSnackBar()
            ..showSnackBar(snackBar);
```